# Vector of class objects corrupted

Tags: c++, vector, mathematical-optimization

I want to create a vector of objects of type T. I've the following:

```
vector<T> objects; //global

void CreateObject(some_params){
   T t = T();
   /* code follows that computes members of t.
      T is a complex class and all members require some computation
      to be given a value */

   objects.push_back(T(t) );  //copy constructor using t and push in vector
}

void funtion1(some_params){
    //iterate over all objects previously pushed, and do some computation.
}

void function2(some_params){
   //iterate over all objects previously pushed, and do some computation.
}

int main(){
  createObject(some_params);
  liboptpp_object.optimize(function1, function2);
}
```

My copy constructor:

```
class T{
    T(const T& t){
      this->member1 = t.member1;
      this->member2 = t.member2;
      /* and so on for all data members */
    }
}
```

As seen from above summarized code, I create a vector of objects. The functions `function1`, `function2` are going to use the objects in this vector to further perform some computation. I'm trying to minimize a mathematical function using `Opt++` library. The `Opt++` instance's`optimize` function takes as arguments pointers to the two functions - `function1` , `function2`. So, these two functions will be called when Opt++ tries to minimize the function. These functions should then operate on the vector of previously created objects and return some values. That's the whole picture.

However, when the two functions are called by Opt++ and when they iterate over the vector of objects, it is seen that most of the objects are corrupted - they have garbage values , values that were not given to them by the `createObject()` method. So the memory these objects had, now contain random values. The `createObject()` method is the only place where these objects are created and pushed. The objects are not modified any where later.

Is there something wrong in the way `createObject` populates this vector of objects; is there some violation of scope or something? I'm not sure what is happening, but I think the way I'm creating the vector is wrong perhaps..

Comment: Sounds like your copy constructor is wrong. Also, why don't you use a [`move constructor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) or [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)?

Comment: I hadn't heard of those, will look into them, thanks!

Comment: The code included in your post does not appear to exhibit the problem you are describing.

Comment: I've updated the post to show my copy constructor. @erip , what is the advantage of move constructor or emplace_back over what I'm doing in the copy constructor?

Comment: It looks like you're doing a shallow copy when you should likely be doing a deep copy. unfortunately you still haven't provided enough code to make that determination.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious yes, I am not doing a deep copy anywhere..

Comment: By using `emplace` first, you make sure you never have to do any copying _or_ moving which will probably fix your issue.  `objects.emplace_back();` and then `T& t = objects.back();`  Try to fill that `t` instead.

Comment: I would change CreateObjects to return the vector by value.  Then declare `const vector<T> objects = CreateObjects();`.  That way, any writing to the vector stands a much better chance of generating compile time error.

Comment: Also, your copy constructor appears to be replaceable by: `T(const T& rhs) = default;`